# How to display an image in react-native from an api and append to baseURL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display an image in react-native from an api and I want to append the fetched value with the base url which is https://lsm-static-prod.livescore.com/medium but image cannot be seen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTsNQ.png)
This is the code. Please help

const baseURL = 'https://lsm-static-prod.livescore.com/medium/'

```
<Image 
   source={baseURL + item.Events[0].T1[0].Img}
             resizeMethod="contain"
             style={{
                     width: 30,
                     height: 30,
                   }}
/>
```

Comment: try : `source={{url : baseURL + item.Events[0].T1[0].Img}}`

Comment: https://lsm-static-prod.livescore.com/medium/betmakers/-1000106450.png try like this just for test: source={{url : https://lsm-static-prod.livescore.com/medium/betmakers/-1000106450.png}}

Answer (score 1):

FOr image in react native :

you should do

source should be extracted like this :

```
const uri =`${baseURL}${item.Events[0].T1[0].Img}`
```

And for uri you need to pass as `source = {{uri:YOUR_URL}}`

```
<Image 
   source={{uri:uri}}
             resizeMethod="contain"
             style={{
                     width: 30,
                     height: 30,
                   }}
/>
```

Hope it works :)